# Showing Elastic Beanstalk environment health text in Cloudwatch widget

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create a Cloudwatch dashboard that has the environment health of various Elastic Beanstalk environments. Currently I have the EnvironmentHealth variable that is 0/5/10/15/20/25 which map to the statuses here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-cloudwatch.html

What I want to do is show the text "OK" if the value is 0 or "Severe" if the value is 25, etc... I'd love to just create a math expression in the cloudwatch graph that does something like `IF(m1 == 0, "OK")` but strings aren't accepted as inputs into the if expression.

Is there a way to easily get the human readable environment health in a cloudwatch dashboard? I'd like to avoid generating custom metrics if possible. Really the simple widget that AWS has in their elastic beanstalk monitoring tab would be perfect.